# When i drag element "div" and drop to "ul" i want to change "div" into "li"

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

When i drag element **div** and drop to **ul** i want to change **div** into **li**

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/7fEQs/

## SCRIPT

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        revert: true
    });
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#sortable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/7fEQs/7/

## JQUERY

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        revert: true,
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).find('div').removeClass('ui-state-highlight ui-draggable').css({'display':''});            
            
            var html = [];
            $(this).find('div').each(function() {
                html.push('<li class="ui-state-default">' + $(this).text() + '</li>');
            });
            $(this).find('div').replaceWith(html.join(''));
        }
    });
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#sortable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
});
```